# Pegar valor dentro do 'ContentControl' de um botão

Tags: c#, eventos, xaml

Tenho o seguinte código em `XAML`:

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnSete" Click="btn_Click">
    <ContentControl>
        <Viewbox Margin="3">
            <TextBlock Text="7"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </ContentControl>           
</Button>
```

e no code behind:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    //txbDisplay.Text = btn.ContentStringFormat.ToString();
}
```

A Dúvida agora é, como faço para no evento de `Click` pegar o conteúdo que está dento de:

```
<ContentControl>
    <Viewbox Margin="3">
        <TextBlock Text="7"/>
    </Viewbox>
</ContentControl>
```

do botão?

Quero mostrar no `txbDisplay` o valor que está em `<TextBlock Text="7"/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

Removi o `<ContentControl>`

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="btnCinco" Click="btn_Click">
    <Viewbox Margin="3">
        <TextBlock Text="5"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Button>
```

e no evento fiz assim:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;

    var viewBox = (Viewbox)btn.Content;
    var txtBlock = (TextBlock)viewBox.Child;
    var text = txtBlock.Text;

    txbDisplay.Text += text;
}
```